Conditional expectation and mutual independence
Let $X,Y,Z$ be mutually independent random variables with range $\mathcal{R}$. Let $f$ be a measurable function from $\mathcal{R}\times\mathcal{R}$ to $\{0,1\}$.
Is it then true that
$E[f(X,Y)f(X,Z)\mid X] = E[f(X,Y)\mid X]\cdot E[f(X,Z)\mid X]$ ?
I feel like this must be true because, informally, "given $X$, $f(X,Y)$ and $f(X,Z)$ are functions of independent random variables, hence independent (given $X$)".
But these are just intuitive words. I'm having a hard time proving this from the definition of conditional expectation.
By definition, I want to show that for every $\sigma(X)$-measurable set $H$ we have
$\int_{H}f(X,Y) f(X,Z) dP = \int_{H}E[f(X,Y)\mid X]\cdot E[f(X,Z)\mid X] dP$.
I'm looking for a proof either by more basic properties of the conditional expectation, or by definition.

This is a good question. Is there a reason you restrict the range of $f$ to ${0, 1}$?

@msantama: Just because this is a simple version that I can't solve.

Let us work in a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ and suppose
$$X : (\Omega, \Sigma) \to (\Lambda, \mathcal{F})$$
$$Y : (\Omega, \Sigma) \to (\Gamma, \mathcal{G})$$
$$Z : (\Omega, \Sigma) \to (\Gamma, \mathcal{G})$$
are mutually independent random variables. Define
$$f(u, v) = \mathbf{1}_{F \times G}(u, v) = \mathbf{1}_{F}(u) \mathbf{1}_{G}(v)$$
with $F \in \mathcal{F}$ and $G \in \mathcal{G}$. Observe
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left[ f(X, Y) f(X, Z) \mid X \right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_{F}(X) \mathbf{1}_G(Y) \mathbf{1}_{F}(X) \mathbf{1}_G(Z) \mid X \right] \\
&\overset{(1)}{=} \mathbf{1}_{F}(X) \mathbf{1}_{F}(X) \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{1}_G(Y) \mathbf{1}_G(Z) \mid X \right] \\
&\overset{(2)}{=} \mathbf{1}_{F}(X) \mathbf{1}_{F}(X) \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{1}_G(Y) \mathbf{1}_G(Z) \right] \\
&\overset{(3)}{=} \mathbf{1}_{F}(X) \mathbf{1}_{F}(X) \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{1}_G(Y) \right] \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_G(Z) \right]
\end{aligned}
The numbered equalities are justified at the end. Furthermore we have
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ f(X, Y) \mid X \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_{F}(X) \mathbf{1}_G(Y) \mid X \right] \overset{(1)}{=} \mathbf{1}_{F}(X) \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_G(Y) \mid X \right] \overset{(4)}{=} \mathbf{1}_{F}(X) \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{1}_G(Y) \right]$$
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ f(X, Z) \mid X \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_{F}(X) \mathbf{1}_G(Z) \mid X \right] = \mathbf{1}_{F}(X) \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{1}_G(Z) \mid X \right] = \mathbf{1}_{F}(X) \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{1}_G(Z) \right]$$
so evidently
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ f(X, Y) f(X, Z) \mid X \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ f(X, Y) \mid X \right] \mathbb{E}\left[ f(X, Z) \mid X \right]$$

Proof of $(1)$. It suffices to show $\mathbf{1}_{F}(X)$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable. For any Borel set $A \in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$
$$\mathbf{1}_{F}(X)^{-1}(A) = \left( X^{-1} \circ \mathbf{1}_F^{-1} \right)(A) = X^{-1}\left( \left\{ u \in \Lambda : \mathbf{1}_{F}(u) \in A \right\} \right)$$
We can consider four cases:
$$\{0, 1\} \cap A = \varnothing \implies \left\{ u \in \Lambda : \mathbf{1}_{F}(u) \in A \right\} = \varnothing \in \mathcal{F}$$
$$\{0, 1\} \cap A = \{0\} \implies \left\{ u \in \Lambda : \mathbf{1}_{F}(u) \in A \right\} = F^\complement \in \mathcal{F}$$
$$\{0, 1\} \cap A = \{1\} \implies \left\{ u \in \Lambda : \mathbf{1}_{F}(u) \in A \right\} = F \in \mathcal{F}$$
$$\{0, 1\} \cap A = \{0, 1\} \implies \left\{ u \in \Lambda : \mathbf{1}_{F}(u) \in A \right\} = \Omega \in \mathcal{F}$$
and we conclude $\mathbf{1}_F(X)$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable.
Proof of $(2)$. It suffices to show $\mathbf{1}_G(Y) \mathbf{1}_G(Z) \perp\!\!\!\perp X$. In particular we must prove
$$\mathbb{P}\left( A \cap B \right) = \mathbb{P}\left( A \right) \mathbb{P}\left( B \right)$$
for all $A \in \sigma\left( \mathbf{1}_G(Y) \mathbf{1}_G(Z) \right)$ and $B \in \sigma(X)$. We can identify the elements of $\sigma\left( \mathbf{1}_G(Y) \mathbf{1}_G(Z) \right)$: take any Borel set $M \in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and consider four cases
$$\{0, 1\} \cap M = \varnothing \implies \Big[ \mathbf{1}_G(Y) \mathbf{1}_G(Z) \Big]^{-1}(M) = \varnothing$$
$$\{0, 1\} \cap M = \{0\} \implies \Big[ \mathbf{1}_G(Y) \mathbf{1}_G(Z) \Big]^{-1}(M) = Y^{-1}(G^{\complement}) \cup Z^{-1}(G^\complement)$$
$$\{0, 1\} \cap M = \{1\} \implies \Big[ \mathbf{1}_G(Y) \mathbf{1}_G(Z) \Big]^{-1}(M) = Y^{-1}(G) \cap Z^{-1}(G)$$
$$\{0, 1\} \cap M = \{0, 1\} \implies \Big[ \mathbf{1}_G(Y) \mathbf{1}_G(Z) \Big]^{-1}(M) = \Omega$$
With $A \in \{\varnothing, \Omega\}$ the result is trivial so we are left with two cases to verify. By mutual independence
$$\mathbb{P}\left( Y^{-1}(G) \cap Z^{-1}(G) \cap B \right) = \mathbb{P}\left( Y^{-1}(G) \right) \mathbb{P}\left( Z^{-1}(G) \right) \mathbb{P}\left( B \right) = \mathbb{P}\left( Y^{-1}(G) \cap Z^{-1}(G) \right) \mathbb{P}\left( B \right)$$
To finish observe
$$Y^{-1}(G^{\complement}) \cup Z^{-1}(G^\complement) = \Big[ Y^{-1}(G) \cap Z^{-1}(G) \Big]^\complement$$
and
$$\mathbb{P}( A^\complement \cap B^\complement ) = \mathbb{P}( A^\complement ) \mathbb{P}( B^\complement ) \implies \mathbb{P}\left( A \cap B\right) = \mathbb{P}\left( A \right) \mathbb{P}\left( B \right)$$
Proof of $(3)$. It suffices to show $\mathbf{1}_G(Y) \perp\!\!\!\perp \mathbf{1}_G(Z)$. By $(1)$ we know $\mathbf{1}_G(Y)$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable and $\mathbf{1}_G(Z)$ is $\sigma(Z)$-measurable. In particular this means
$$\sigma\left( \mathbf{1}_G(Y) \right) \subseteq \sigma(Y)$$
$$\sigma\left( \mathbf{1}_G(Z) \right) \subseteq \sigma(Z)$$
and independence follows immediately.
Proof of $(4)$. It suffices to show $\mathbf{1}_G(Y) \perp\!\!\!\perp X$. By $(1)$ we know $\mathbf{1}_G(Y)$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable. In particular this means
$$\sigma\left( \mathbf{1}_G(Y) \right) \subseteq \sigma(Y)$$
and independence follows immediately.

Thank you so much! Am I right that you are taking $f$ to be of a special form? To deduce the general case, do you mean we should rely on some density result of such functions in the space of all measurable functions?

Yes, I’m taking $f$ to be an indicator function here. The “standard machine” of analysis should extend the result to general $f$

I see, thank you for this great answer. I must say that I am surprised that I have not been able to find a reference from which this can be deduced in one or two lines.

Here is a method that uses the standard "tower property" and "taking out what is known" for conditional expectations, along with a simpler claim.
Let $X,Y,Z$ be mutually independent. Let $f, g$ be measurable real-valued functions that are bounded. Assume $f, g$ have appropriate domains so that $f(X,Y)$ and $g(X,Z)$ are well defined bounded random variables.  Boundedness assures us that $f(X,Y)$ and $g(X,Z)$ have finite expectations.
Claim 1: Since $Y$ is independent of $(X,Z)$ we have almost surely:
$$E[g(X,Z)|X,Y]=E[g(X,Z)|X] \quad (Eq. 1)$$
Claim 1 immediately implies the desired equality because
\begin{align}
&E[f(X,Y)g(X,Z)|X]\\
&\overset{(a)}{=}E[\: E[f(X,Y)g(X,Z)|X,Y]\: |X]\\
&\overset{(b)}{=}E[\: f(X,Y)E[g(X,Z)|X,Y] \: | X]\\
&\overset{(c)}{=}E[\: f(X,Y)E[g(X,Z)|X]\: |X]\\
&\overset{(d)}{=}E[g(X,Z)|X]E[f(X,Y) \: |X]
\end{align}
where (a) holds by the tower property; (b) pulls out the measurable function of $(X,Y)$; (c) uses (Eq. 1); (d) pulls out $E[g(X,Z)|X]$, which is a measurable function of $X$.

The Claim 1, while intuitive, is surprisingly difficult to prove. It may require something like the "Dynkin multiplicative system theorem." See, for example, Section 11.1 in "Analysis Tools with Examples" by Bruce K. Driver.
Specifically, for simplicity, assume $X,Y$ are real-valued random variables. We shall prove Claim 1 for measurable functions $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that are bounded. Define $H$ as the set of all such measurable and bounded functions $g$ that satisfy
$$E[g(X,Z)|X,Y]=E[g(X,Z)|X] \quad \mbox{almost surely}$$
Define $M$ as the set of functions that have a product form
$$ g(x,z)=h(x)r(z) \quad \forall x,z\in\mathbb{R}$$
for measurable and bounded $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $r:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  It is clear that $M$ is a "multiplicative system," meaning that the product of a finite number of functions in $M$ is yet another function in $M$. Also, it is easy to check that $M$ is a subset of $H$.
Dynkin's multiplicative system theorem says that if (i) $H$ contains all constant functions, (ii) $H$ is closed under bounded convergence, then $H$ contains all bounded real-valued functions that are $\sigma(M)$-measurable. [In this case, a $\sigma(M)$-measurable function means a Borel measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, since the sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^2$ generated by the product-form functions is just $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.]
To check points (i) and (ii)
(i) It is easy to see $H$ contains all constant functions.
(ii) Let $g_n$ be a sequence of functions in $H$ such that there is a finite constant $b$ such that $|g_n(x,z)|\leq b$ for all $x,z\in\mathbb{R}$, $n\in\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ that satisfy $g_n(x,y)\rightarrow g(x,y)$ pointwise for some $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. We need to show $g\in H$.  Since $g$ is the pointwise limit of uniformly bounded and measurable functions, $g$ must be bounded and measurable. Since $g_n\in H$ for all $n$ we know
$$ E[g_n(X,Z)|X,Y]=E[g_n(X,Z)|X] \quad \mbox{almost surely}$$
Since $|g_n(x,z)|\leq b$ for all $n,x,z$ and $g_n\rightarrow g$ pointwise, it can be shown that we can pass the limit through the (conditional) expectation, so (almost surely) we get
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[g_n(X,Z)|X,Y]=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[g_n(X,Z)|X]$$
$$E[g(X,Z)|X,Y]=E[g(X,Z)|X]$$
and so $g\in H$.
[The fact about passing limits through conditional expectations is itself nontrivial but seems to have a short proof. It can be viewed as a conditional version of the bounded convergence theorem. However, this "easy claim 1" is really getting out of hand!]

Nicely done! I was looking for a solution along these lines. I’d be curious to see a proof of that claim

Thanks. I originally thought the claim would be easy, but now I think otherwise. I have added a note about it in my answer.

But since $Y$ is independent of $(X,Z)$ , claim 1 is trivial. The distribution of $(X,Z)$ does not change when conditioning by $Y$.

Just invoking the definition of independence is not a proof. As I said, Claim 1 is intuitive but surprisingly difficult to prove. The definition of conditioning on a sigma algebra is what is needed. Arguments about joint pdf are not sufficient, joint pdf does not always exist.

I do not invoke any definition, I expose a property: $(X,Z)$ and $(X,Z)|Y$ are exactly the same and therefore the expectations in claim 1. Even so, I send you a trivial proof:
$$E[1_A(X)1_B(Y)E[g(X,Z)|X]]= E[1_B(Y)]E[1_A(X)E[g(X,Z)|X]]=E[1_B(Y)]E[1_A(X)g(X,Z)]= E[1_B(Y)1_A(X)g(X,Z)]$$

Your equations are correct but they do not prove anything. You need to prove that $E[g(X,Z)1_{{(X,Y)\in A}}]=E[E[g(X,Z)|X]1_{{(X,Y)\in A}}]$ for all Borel $A \subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$. The difficulty is that $1_{{(X,Y)\in A}}$ is not in product form. That is why I used the Dynkin multiplicative system theorem.

I imagine that there is no need to demonstrate the Monotone Convergence Theorem here.

I find that David Williams in Probability with Martingales lists a version of Claim 1 as Property 9.7.k "Role of independence:" $E[X|\sigma(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H})] = E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ if $\mathcal{H}$ is independent of $\sigma(\sigma(X),\mathcal{G})$.  He proves it using a $\pi$-system theorem rather than a multiplicative system theorem (his proof is easier). His Properties 9.7i, 9.7j, 9.7g are what I am using above for "Tower property" and "taking out what is known" (I used that same terminology based on past reads of his book) and also  "conditional dominated convergence."

I insist that claim 1 is trivial. None of these demonstrations are necessary.

The result of Claim 1 is true whether you view it as obvious or as needing a foundational proof. I understand why it might be viewed as "obvious." I sectioned off my answer to the first part (using Claim 1, tower property, taking out what is known) to prove the question of the OP; the second part is my own exploration of the foundational issue of proving Claim 1. In retrospect, the David Williams approach to Claim 1 is likely better. While Claim 1 is intuitive, I prefer to see an axiomatic approach that stays as close to definitions or basic results as possible.

$$E[f(X,Y)f(X,Z)\mid X=x]=E[f(x,Y)f(x,Z)\mid X=x]=E[f(x,Y)]\cdot E[f(x,Z)]$$
Therefore:
$$E[f(X,Y)f(X,Z)\mid X]=E[f(X,Y)\mid X]\cdot E[f(X,Z)\mid X]$$

Thank you. I think this argument is only valid for discrete probability distributions. I am looking for a proof in the general case.

Why do you think that?

X=x would be a zero probability event for most continuous distributions, so conditioning on it is not well defined. Yet, conditional expectation can be defined axiomatically, and shown to exist using a Radon-Nikodym derivative. If there's a way to make sense of it in the continuous case by conditioning on $X=x$ in some sense, then I haven't learned it yet.

The formula $E[f(X,Y)|X=x]=E[f(x,Y)|X=x]$ is widely used in probability in both the discrete and continuous cases. Do you think it is invalid?

I think this formula is valid only as long as $E[f(X,Y)\mid X=x]$ is well defined, which happens exactly when $P(X=x)>0$. Is there a way to make sense of it when $P(X=x)=0$? But even in the case where $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x$, it is still possible to define the conditional expectation given $X$ (rather than given $X=x$). For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent uniform random variables on the interval $[0,1]$, then $E[X+Y\mid X]=X+\frac{1}{2}$. I'm just learning all of this, so maybe I missed the reason conditioning on $X=x$ is possible in the setting of my question.

$E[X+Y\mid X=x]=E[x+Y\mid X=x]=E[x+Y]=x+1/2$

$E[X+Y\mid X]=X+1/2$ and $E[X+Y\mid X=x]=x+1/2$ mean the same thing.

But doesn't the definition of $P(A\mid B)$ require $P(B)>0$ to make sense? The definition I know is $P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$. If $P(B)=0$, we have division by zero which is undefined. What definition are you working with?
